# variable has initializer but incomplete type C++

Tags: c++, struct, compiler-errors

I am new to C++. I have this code to create a struct, to show the usage of `mutable` keyword in C++.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  struct
  {
    mutable double radius;
    double PI = 3.142;

    double getArea()
    {
      return (PI * radius * radius);
    }
  } circle;

  const struct circle c1 = {2.0};
  circle.radius = 7;

  cout << "Area is " << circle.getArea() << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

But I get the following error message when compiling:

```
error: variable const main()::circle c1 has initializer but incomplete type
```

Error is at `c1` in the line `const struct circle c1 = {2.0};`. Can anyone point me out the error here.

Comment: You almost certainly don't want `mutable` there.  OTOH, PI should probably be `static constexpr double` (you don't want different copies of PI if you have different  circles).  Annoyingly, you then have to move the declaration of circle outside main.  Finally, don't use `using namespace std;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you put the name `circle` after the right brace at the end of the `struct` definition, you're declaring a variable.

Put it at the start, after the word `struct`, to declare a type.

I.e.

```
struct circle
{
    // ...
};
```

---

In other news:

- You'll need to declare `getArea()` as `const` to be able to call it on a `const` instance, i.e. `double getArea() const`.
- You don't need the `return 0;` at the end, because that's the default for `main`. There is no such default for other functions. `main` is special.
- In order to use `cout` unqualified (as it seems you want to) you can add `using namespace std;` at the start of the code; it's usually placed after the includes.

---

`mutable` is usually not used to allow *outside* code to treat part of an object as always non-`const`.

Instead it's used as a device to more easily let a class implementation have some non-`const` state also when the object *appears to be `const`* to outside code. That's called **logical constness**. For example, the object might cache the result of an expensive computation, even when it's `const`.

In C++17 and later `mutable` can also be applied to lambda expressions, where it yields a lambda that can change its state (captured values).

Comment: You don't *need* `return 0;` at the end of main - but I would say it is poor style not to do so.  I would recommend avoiding `using namespace std;` and qualify `cout` and `endl`.

Comment: @MartinBonner: It's certainly not poor style to omit the `return` in `main` for a trivial program. On the contrary, since source code mainly communicates to readers, adding a `return` there as if the code is dealing with failures, when it's not, is to communicate an untruth to the reader. And that is, IMNSHO opinion, poor style.

Comment: I disagree.  Explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: Regarding `using namespace std;`, that's fine in a small program like this. An alternative is to use individual `using` declarations, like in Modula-2. I find the the code resulting from qualifying most every name with a namespace, unreadable. There is no need for that with modern technology. C++'s `using` is part of that modern technology. It's there to let programmers *avoid* explicit qualification, to produce readable code. Otherwise one could just just C style fixed prefixes (ugh).

Comment: @MartinBonner: I think I'm the one who has promoted the "explicit is better than implicit". It's generally good to be explicit. Except when that results in communicating false stuff and increasing verbosity.

Answer (score 7):

You don't define a structure named `circle`, you define a *variable* named `circle`. This variable can not be used as a type.

You should do e.g. `struct circle { ... };` to define the structure as a type. Then you could do

```
const circle c1 = { 2.0 };
c1.radius = 7;
std::cout << c1.getArea() << '\n';
```

There are a few other problems, most notable you don't declare the `getArea` function as `const` which means you can't call it on `const` objects.